# Какой url использовать для фильтра?

Tags: url, cms, seo, поисковая-оптимизация

Делаю фильтр для CMS самописной и нужен более правильный вариант для сео и при этом, чтобы было красиво?

есть такие варианты:

```
site.hi/size_from-150~to-200/color_belyy~goluboy/
site.hi/size_150-200/color_belyy~goluboy/
site.hi/size_150,200/color_belyy,goluboy/
site.hi/size:40+color:white+socket:am4,1700/
site.hi/size_30~100/color_black/socket_am4,1700/
```

предложите свой вариант, чтобы и гугл был доволен и яндекс. желательно без знака `-` ибо есть конфликт и нужно делать проверки) знаю, что поисковики любят - этот знако, но быть может есть варианты?